# can't create Eventhub using ARM template

Tags: azure-eventhub

I'm using ARM template to create Eventhub. I'm not updating any properties in Namespace while creating Eventhub. Till now it was working but failing suddenly with error.

```
  "error": {
    "message": "Updating the KafkaEnabled property on a namespace is not supported. CorrelationId: 78c17059-28db-4039-a980-03aebe849d81",
    "code": "BadRequest"
  }
```

Comment: We are seeing the same error, starting a few hours ago. We have not changed any properties, certainly nothing related with Kafka. It might be an MS issue.

Comment: Which region are you experiencing this in? We are seeing the issue in westus, but not in westeu.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ongoing issue and our product team is currently investigating. The impacted customers should be getting updates from Azure Service Health on Azure portal. (aka.ms/ASH)

The issue has been resolved.

Comment: We are getting this error in west Europe region. Kindly let us know when this will get resolved as we have a timeline to give the setup to the client.

Comment: The issue seems to be resolved as I'm not getting the error while creating eventhub using ARM template. Thanks for your support.